# Retrieve data from PFObject - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, pfobject

I want to retrieve a NSDictionary : "serverData" from a PFObject: "obj". But "serverData" is always nil. Am i wrong somewhere?

[image]

Comment: can you show the objects array ?

Comment: @balkaransingh Sure! I've got 23 object in objects array

Comment: that 23 object are PFobject ? show me the value.

Comment: @balkaransingh Yep, they are PFObject https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B53hTXWovzMUb09Ya1ljOFVZRVU

Comment: below you also show serverData with 12 key value pair ?

Comment: @balkaransingh i already show serverDate with 12 key value pair in my question's image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123201/discussion-between-nguyen-tho-and-balkaran-singh).